# Exchange OAuth settings in 3rd party apps don't allow you to reffer to specific folders in a mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to configure a mailbox on Exchange Online to be used by our Deskpro ticketing system to manage several queues. The only way I could setup Deskpro to recognise different folders in the mailbox was to make the connection using EWS. MS said they would be deprecating EWS Basic Auth in October last year, does that mean my EWS connection via outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx is now authenticating through OAuth? It still works, I'm concerned MS will change something and it'll stop working.

I'd love to use the OAuth via Graph, but if I select that option in the Deskpro setup there's no way to identify individual folders for each queue to process meaning I'd have to have a separate mailbox for each queue requiring an Exchange Plan license for each!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collin, yes there is an announcement made to deprecate EWS Basic auth (it was made quite some time earlier too) and move to modern auth/oAuth too - it will work for you. Also you know that no new investments are going to be made in EWS, so you wont get any new features. So keeping in that mind, you can use EWS modern auth/oAuth for a while, but i would recommend you to create plan to move to Microsoft Graph API - so that you can interact with all the existing features in EWS and connect with entire Microsoft Graph ecosystem's product/solutions as well.

Comment: Thanks, what I was trying to understand is, will the EWS connection use modern Authentication and it sounds like it will. That will do me. If they promise to do no more investment (ie modify the way it works) that's a good thing, some consistency for once. That's a good thing! This is a configuration in a third party app and once it connects and works, that will be it. It won't be trying to use any fancy features.

Comment: Thanks @Collin for the update - Yes you use modern auth with EWS. Glad to hear that the above helped you move forward. Consider upvoting the answer and accept the answer as well - so it can be useful to other members in the community as well :)